# Remove specific elements from json array

Tags: json, jolt

Received JSON:

```json
  {
    "id": 313,
    "status": "blocked",
    "audit_pixels": [
      {
        "audit_pixel": "134307&ord={{random}}",
        "id": 1470355,
        "parent_id": null,
        "role": null
      },
      {
        "audit_pixel": "1087125871&ord={{random}}",
        "id": 1470356,
        "parent_id": 1470355,
        "role": "originalShow"
      },
      {
        "audit_pixel": "cid1115596-posid2396249",
        "id": 1470359,
        "parent_id": 1470357,
        "role": "originalShow"
      },
      {
        "audit_pixel": "cid1115596-posid2396249/{{random}}",
        "id": 1470360,
        "parent_id": 1470357,
        "role": "playbackStarted"
      },
      {
        "audit_pixel": "cid1115596-posid2396249/{{random}}",
        "id": 1470361,
        "parent_id": 1470357,
        "role": "playheadReachedValue100"
      }
    ]
  }
```

I want to remove elements from array `audit_pixels`:

- where field `role` is **null**,
- where field `role` role is not `originalShow`

**EXPECTED RESULT**:

```json
  {
    "id": 313,
    "status": "blocked",
    "audit_pixels": [
      {
        "audit_pixel": "1087125871&ord={{random}}",
        "role": "originalShow"
      },
      {
        "audit_pixel": "cid1115596-posid2396249",
        "role": "originalShow"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Is it possible? I tried with:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "id": "[&1].id",
        "status": "[&1].status",
        "audit_pixels": {
          "*": {
            "role": {
              "null": {
                "@(3,id)": "null"
              },
              "originalShow": {
                "@(3,id)": "audit_pixels.[&1]"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following transformation :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "audit_pixels": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2.@1,role.@1,id.&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "audit_pixels": {
        "originalShow": {
          "*": {
            "audit_pixel|role": "&3[#2].&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the **demo** on the site https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]

Comment: i'm sorry, maybe i was wrong at my description. I need role `originalShow`, but not others

Comment: Doesn't matter, just fixed it @fujidaon

Comment: Can u please also adapt this to if there only one element (json has only 1 object, not array like it was before)? Updated input and expected

Comment: Also I need only `audit_pixel` and `role` fields

Comment: just edited @fujidaon

Comment: Just tried, in jolt demo it returns null and nothing else :(

Comment: Because I hadn't realized that you've tweaked the input then. Now, you can retry @fujidaon